# QtCore.Signal works in Spyder but not via commandline or IPython

Tags: python, qt

I wrote a program that works fine when I run it within IDE Spyder, but when I start the program from the commandline it does not work. The problem relates to QtCore.Signal. The problem can be reproduced with just a few lines of code on the commandline or within IPython:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
class SimulationSignal(QtCore.QObject):
    sig = QtCore.Signal(str)
```

The subsequent error is as follows:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-db33219da0dd> in <module>()
      1 from PyQt4 import QtCore
----> 2 class SimulationSignal(QtCore.QObject):
      3     sig = QtCore.Signal(str)

<ipython-input-4-db33219da0dd> in SimulationSignal()
      1 from PyQt4 import QtCore
      2 class SimulationSignal(QtCore.QObject):
----> 3     sig = QtCore.Signal(str)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Signal'
```

---

If I remove the QtCore.Signal code then the program runs also from the commandline. I checked that the Qt versions are the same when I run in- or outside of Spyder. They are as follows:
('Qt version:', '4.8.4')
('SIP version:', '4.14.2')
('PyQt version:', '4.9.6')

Any ideas how I might solve this? I would like to make a pyinstaller distributable, but it does not seem to work because of this issue.

Comment: what happens if you `print QtCore.__file__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `PyQt4`, [you need to use `QtCore.pyqtSignal`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), not `QtCore.Signal`. `QtCore.Signal` is the equivalent class when using [`PySide`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Signal.html). I'm not sure how this code is working inside Spyder, unless it's not actually using `PyQt4`.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the solution. I wasn't aware of the different syntax. It is weird that it still works within Spyder.